# What percentage of African Americans speak identifiable African American Vernacular English?

Tags: reference-request, american-english, aave

I'm looking for (reasonably) scientific statistics on the percentage of African Americans whose speech is sufficiently inflected with AAVE that their speech is identifiable as such.  (It would be interesting to know how many non-African Americans would be identified as speaking AAVE, but that's secondary for me.)

I'm not sure what the methodology would be for "identfication", because it's essentially subjective, but I'll take any data at all for now.

Comment: Because many speakers of dialect can and do switch, to the point of not being identifiable, you should define more precisely what you are looking for (ability to speak AAVE, or ability to speak something more neutral, or something else).